# Comma Separated sequence in a single line using Scala

Tags: scala

```scala
for(i <- 10 to 28) {
  if(i % 7 == 0 && i % 5 != 0) {
    println(s"$i")
  }
}
```

Output will be :

14

21

28

Need output like: 14,21,28.....
can anyone help us writing the code in Scala.

Comment: Instead of printing, create a `List[String]`, then join it with `", "`.

Comment: can u tell me the exact code instead of printing

Comment: `collection.filter(predicate).reduceOption(howToCombine).getOrElse(valueForEmptyCollection)` and then print it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this w/o foreach as below

```
val result = (10 to 28).filter(i => (i % 7 == 0 && i % 5 != 0 ) ).mkString(",")
println(result)
```